# How to install vim plugins (abolish.vim) into the IDEA Vim emulator in Intelij?

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, vim-plugin, ideavim

I am using the IdeaVim plugin in intelij, and want to install the [abolish.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) plugin to use with it.  Is this possible?

The IdeaVim [documentation](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#emulated-vim-plugins) doesn't seem to mention if it is.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't install any vim plugin, only emulated ones. This one is not implemented, so you can't use it. You can vote for this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1326

Comment: I thought that might be the case, thanks for the response.